# Import vis.js with webpack

Tags: webpack, vis.js

I would like to import *only* `DataSet` and `Network` from `vis.js` in our Webpack application using ES6 modules.

One easy way to do it is to just import `dist/vis-network.min.js` but it's already minified so not very compatible with our webpack workflow.

I had a look at the vis.js code and it's not using ES6 modules so I can't `import` them.

Is there a simpler way then doing a [custom vis.js build](https://github.com/almende/vis#example-3-bundle-visjs-as-part-of-your-commonjs-application)?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: @JohnnyQ I just customized the gulp file.

Comment: Webpack now supports commonjs, amd and es6 module syntax. See here for an example: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/mixed

Answer (score 0):

It is not only possible but encouraged to import only the parts of vis.js that you want to use in your application. This lets you only load the parts of vis.js that you'll need in your project.

There is [not much documentation](https://github.com/almende/vis/blob/master/README.md#example-4-integrate-visjs-components-directly-in-your-webpack-build) on this topic, but there is a [demo project](https://github.com/mojoaxel/vis-webpack-demo) that shows how to selectively import parts of vis.js using webpack.

Answer (score 0):

There is ability to create your own packs with vis.js.

For doing it you should:

Open file gulpfile.js and add config to INDIVIDUAL_BUNDLES.

For example:

```
var INDIVIDUAL_BUNDLES = [
 {entry: './index-timeline-graph2d.js', filename: 'vis-timeline-
    graph2d.min.js'},
 {entry: './index-network.js', filename: 'vis-network.min.js'},
 {entry: './index-graph3d.js', filename: 'vis-graph3d.min.js'},
 {entry: './index-graph3d.js', filename: 'vis-graph3d.js', 'notMini': 
  true}
];
```

There added config for vis-graph3d not minified.

For not mini network, I assume config will be:

```
 {entry: './index-network.js', filename: 'vis-network.js', 'notMini': true},
```

Or you can write your own bundle.

After change file your should make build (see README.md) shortly:

```
$ cd vis
$ npm install
$ npm run build
```

After in dist folder you can find vis-network.js.