# Polymer3 element with visjs

Tags: css, polymer, vis.js, polymer-3.x, lit-element

With Polymer2 I made an [app](http://spoggy.herokuapp.com/) ([github repo](https://github.com/scenaristeur/heroku-spoggy)) that [uses](https://github.com/scenaristeur/heroku-spoggy/blob/master/public/src/spoggy-graph/spoggy-graph.html) vis.js to create a graph.

But with Polymer3 and LitElement I'm very confused how to include css & png
I've found this discussion for packaging with webpack 
[Import vis.js with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40973055/import-vis-js-with-webpack) 
and a repo here : https://github.com/mojoaxel/vis-webpack-demo

and it looks ok, but is it possible make a Polymer3 element with vis.js 
that looks like this image?

[image: image Polymer3 visjs element]

The problem is that it must import /node_modules/vis/dist/vis-network.min.css and that this css use png images in /node_modules/vis/dist/img/network/

I'm looking for a way to import this css + its png.
Thxs

Comment: What css are you talking about? Vis.js generates canvas, it doesn't account css (except for edit panel and some exotic usage of svg inside nodes)

Comment: @Yakovl exactly, i'd like to use navigation & manipulation (edit) functions

Comment: as i had here with Polymer 2 : http://spoggy.herokuapp.com/